# Word_tokenize does not work after sent_tokenize in python dataframe

Tags: python, nlp

I trying to tokenize by data using sent_tokenize and word_tokenize.

Below is my dummy data

> ```
> **text**
> Hello world, how are you
> I am fine, thank you!
> ```

I am trying to tokenize it using below code

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
Corpus=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Desktop\NLP\corpus.csv",encoding='utf-8')

Corpus['text']=Corpus['text'].apply(sent_tokenize)
Corpus['text_new']=Corpus['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

but it is giving below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gunjit.bedi/Desktop/NLP Project/Topic Classification.py", line 24, in <module>
    Corpus['text_new']=Corpus['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3192, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx", line 1472, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 128, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 95, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1241, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1291, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1291, in <listcomp>
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1281, in span_tokenize
    for sl in slices:
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1322, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 313, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py", line 1295, in _slices_from_text
    for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I did try a lot of things like if I comment sent_tokenize , the word_tokenize works but both of them do not work together

Comment: `Corpus['text1']=Corpus['text'].apply(sent_tokenize)` try this. If this makes both your sentences work, then it means whatever the output you get after sent_tokenize it is not inline with what word_tokenize expect..and hence the error

Comment: Corpus['text1']=Corpus['text'].apply(sent_tokenize) and Corpus['text2']=Corpus['text'].apply(word_tokenize)
The above code does work but this does not solve my issue of running them one after the other

Comment: So, did you above comment worked ?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting an error because `nltk.word_tokenize` expects input as `string`.

When you apply `nltk.sent_tokenize` on text it converts it into list.

```
text = ['Hey. Hello','hello world!! I am akshay','I m fine']

df['text']=df['text'].apply(sent_tokenize)
print(df['text'])
```

Output:

```
                           text
0                 [Hey., Hello]
1  [hello world!!, I am akshay]
2                    [I m fine]
```

**Try this**

```
df['sent']=df['text'].apply(lambda x :sent_tokenize(str(x)))

df['text_new']= [word_tokenize(str(i)) for i in df['sent']]
```